# Can't download (update) files in iCloud Drive over Cellular

Tags: icloud

I can't download (update) files in iCloud Drive on my iPhone 6 over 4G connection. It only works with WiFi. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Please see this image which shows you how to enable cellular data.

[image]

Source: http://www.imore.com/how-enable-or-disable-icloud-drive-syncing-over-cellular

Comment: On iOS 12, this "Use Cellular Data" toggle has moved to: Settings > Mobile > iCloud Drive (near the very bottom, after the toggles for individual apps).

Answer (score 3):

This happens when cellular data for iCloud is switched OFF:

1. Go to Settings
2. Select Cellular
3. Scroll down to the bottom and switch ON the ICLOUD

By doing this, you can now download files from iCloud using cellular data.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my iPhone8 and got it resolved with Apple Support.  Apparently, while the settings (mobile data on, iCloud enabled) may be correct, the phone may not detect them correctly.  The solution is to turn mobile data off, shut down the phone.  Start the phone up again and then turn mobile data back on.  Shutting down the phone must be done differently for this to work.  Press volume down, press volume up, then press and hold the power button until the apple logo appears.

Comment: I know this is a very old post but this worked for me on iOS 15.0.2 in 2021!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out after half a year...

1. **MAKE SURE YOUR SETTINGS HAS CELLULAR DATA ON!**

Steps : Settings> Cellular> Scroll & find "Settings" > turn on
[image]

it should work by then.. if not the second step would be @robs post.

(Thank you rob for your post! it made me check the cellular data when it didn't pop up in icloud menu)

Answer (score -2):

The way I solved that issue is to logoff from and login in icloud and turn plane mode on for 30s. See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8246057.

Comment: This answer was already provided in a [previous answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/326074/88313).  See [answer] for tips in answering questions.

Comment: Well, turning mobile data on and off is not the same thing as logging off iCloud and logging back. I have tried the other solutions to no avail : this one worked.

Comment: It effectively is the same.  Plus, you stated 'turn plan mode on for 30s' which is what was already provided. You can earn more reputation on the site and add comments to the previous answer or upvote those answers that helped you.

Comment: "It effectively is the same." : That is a strange thing to write. How can turning mobile data on and off and logging off and in iCloud be the same ?
"turn plan mode on for 30s' which is what was already provided." : Where ? I might be dense, but I read no allusion to that on that page.